# All image url not accepting all images

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-api-2

I need to convert image URL into bitmap then have to apply that into marker in Mapv2. I am using image loader class from where i am converting image URL into bitmap.

When i am using rectangle image URL then i am able to show a image on my current location at market but when i am using balloon image URL bitmap is not working showing null pointer exception

```
 public class Demo extends FragmentActivity {

        String lat;
        String lon;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        Bitmap bm;
        ImageLoader imageloader;
        String url ="url";
        Bitmap bitmap ;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.flirtalerthome_screen);
            logout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoutimage);

            imageloader = new ImageLoader(Demo.this.getApplicationContext());
            bm = imageloader.getBitmap(url);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();

        }

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

            if (mMap == null) {

                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                if (mMap != null) {

                    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20),
                                    2000, null);
                             mMap.clear();

                                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()))
                                    .title("its my location")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)));


                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void setUpMap() {

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title(
                    "Marker"));
        }




    }
```

Here is the ImageLoader class

```
 public class ImageLoader {

        MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
        FileCache fileCache;
        private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
        ExecutorService executorService; 

        public ImageLoader(Context context){
            fileCache=new FileCache(context);
            executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        }

        int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
        {

            stub_id = loader;
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
            {
                queuePhoto(url, imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(loader);
            }
        }

        private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
        {
            PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
            executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
        {
            File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

            //from SD cache
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if(b!=null)
                return b;

            //from web
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
            }
        }

        //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
            try {
                //decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;
                    scale*=2;
                }

                //decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            return null;
        }

        //Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad
        {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
                url=u;
                imageView=i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
                this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
            }


            public void run() {
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            }
        }

        boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
            public void run()
            {
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                if(bitmap!=null)
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                else
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        public void clearCache() {
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the baloon image URL in your browser. Does your bitmap loads in the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use ImageLoader class, instead of it, use AndroidQuery, it is very fast and it is working for many stuffs.

Download jar from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Code:

```
private AQuery androidAQuery;
androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

    androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: actually now i want to show a multiple images om map. With single image it's working fine but for multiple its not.Tell me how to do for multiple images

Comment: put it in loop and pass url one by one.

Comment: actually i did this already but it is not giving bitmap properly it is showing null pointer Exception ,it's working fine with single image.

Comment: can you suggest me how to show convert all user images into bitmap